# Angular watch changes on another instance from the same directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement the classic `Country > State > City` combobox using angular directives.

I'm willing to link them by a custom attribute pair `name/depends-on`, but I don't know if there's a better form.

My HTML is the following:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <multiselect source-url="/countries.json" auto-init="true" name="Contries">
    <select multiple ng-model="$parent.selectedOptions" ng-change="$parent.handleChange()">
      <optgroup ng-repeat="(continent, countries) in $parent.optionList" label="{{continent}}">
        <option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.code}}">
          {{country.code}} - {{country.name}}
        </option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
  </multiselect>
  <multiselect source-url="/states.json" depends-on="Countries" name="States">
    <select multiple ng-model="$parent.selectedOptions" ng-change="$parent.handleChange()">
      <optgroup ng-repeat="(continent, countries) in $parent.optionList" label="{{continent}}">
        <option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.code}}"> {{country.code}} - {{country.name}}
        </option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
  </multiselect>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
app.directive('multiselect', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      sourceUrl : '@',
      autoInit : '@',
      dependsOn : '@'
    },
    controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$transclude', '$http', function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude, $http) {

      $scope.handleChange = function handleChange() {
        console.log($scope.selectedOptions)
      }

      console.log($scope.dependsOn)

      function updateSource() {
        const config = {
          params : {}
        }

        if ($scope.dependsOn) {
          // how do I get dependsOnValue?????
          config.params[$scope.dependsOn.toLowerCase()] = $scope.dependsOnValue
        }

        $http.get($scope.sourceUrl, config)
          .then(function (response) {
            $scope.optionList = response.data
          })
      }

      if ($scope.autoInit) {
        updateSource()
      }
    }],
    template: '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>'
  }
})
```

The question is: how do I watch for changes in `Countries` in order to get its value to update `States`?

I'm trying to make this as reusable as possible.

Comment: What does `$parent.selectedOptions` represent? Is it a property of `Ctrl` controller and why is it same for both Countries and States directive instances?

Comment: To be honest, this is like that because it was a way I found to have the controller watch to changes in this. I started with a single instance of the directive and that was how I made it work. But you are right, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The reason why I'm asking is you could introduce `selectedOptionCountries` and `selectedOptionStates` for their respective directive instances. Then, you can have something like `depends-on-value="selectedOptionsCountries"` on the States instance and `dependsOnValue : '=?'` in your directive.

Comment: I was reading a little more about angular directives during the weekend and your approach now seems promising :). I'll try that and come back with the results.